# Is this an appropriate closing?

Tags: discussion

I had found an elegant solution to an issue at work that I felt could be shared.

A user then commented with a wrong answer; was told it was wrong. Then answered with a valid (yet less efficient) answer. Then deleted that answer and then summarily closed the question.

Is this appropriate?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376609/how-can-i-sort-a-list-of-titles-in-php-in-alphabetic-order-that-contain-numbers?noredirect=1#comment54556706_33376609

Comment: It was closed as a dupe, and the dupe does seem to cover your usecase.

Comment: Eh, that user's actions were a bit sketch, but, as from the dupe, *"due to the enormous and ever repeating amount of "How do I sort my unique snowflake of an array?" questions, this is a reference collection of basic sorting methods in PHP. Please close any question which does not markedly differ as a duplicate of this one."* which is quite appropriate, I feel.

Comment: @Will Really?  I see nothing wrong with what they did.  I have, on occasion, answered a question only to later realize that there's a canonical question on the topic with higher quality answers than mine, and thus closed the question and removed my answer.  The only reason it would be problematic is if he knew it was a dupe before posting his answer and choose not to close it right away, and I see no indication of that.

Comment: Yeah, if anything this is the least sketchy thing to do for a gold badge holder.

Comment: @Servy I said their actions were a *bit* sketch.  Calm thy chests.

Comment: @Will And I said that it's not, and explained why.  Who's not calm?

Comment: The user did seem a bit... annoyed, but that's it. No wrong doing or shady actions involved.

Comment: @Servy You've interpreted my use of slang incorrectly, I'd wager. I agreed with the OP that it *looks like* the closer *may have* done something unethical.

Comment: @Will And I disagreed with you and explained why he didn't do anything unethical at all; he in fact did everything correctly.

Comment: @Servy lemme try this one more time, after which I'm done--*looking like* you did something *possibly unethical* is **not** the same as *doing something unethical*.  I don't think he did something unethical. But it's easy to see how someone else may think he **had**.  And that's the end of it.  Good day to you, sir.

Answer (score 6):

The question is closed as a duplicate, meaning you can (and should) simply post your answer to the canonical question, rather than the duplicate.  (Assuming that the canonical question would benefit from your answer; apparently in this specific case the canonical question already has an answer with your solution, so there is no reason to post it again.)